# How to update ListBox with ObservableCollection WPF MVVC?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observable

I'm learning WPF MVVM pattern. I've been following Sean Singleton tutorial on YT and so far I've understood and managed to apply the patter to my application.

However there is one aspect that I don't understand what's happening...

I have a view with ListBox that has `Binding` to `ObservableCollection` on `ViewModel`.
ViewModel inherits from `ViewModelBase` which in turn introduced '`NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Sean did some method to update the collection by clearing it first and then fetching all values again... Surely as ObservableCollection I should be able to add an item and it should notify the UI that something has changed?

So what I have so far(unnecessary code was removed for better readibility)

View

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10 10"  BorderBrush="{StaticResource DHLYellow}" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Bookings}">
```

ViewModelBase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GIO.UI.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

BookingListingViewModel

```
using GIO.Interfaces;
using GIO.Services;
using GIO.UI.Commands;
using GIO.UI.Stores;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace GIO.UI.ViewModels
{
    public class BookingListingViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private ObservableCollection<BookingViewModel> _bookings;

        private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;

        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel => _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel;

        public IEnumerable<BookingViewModel> Bookings => _bookings;

        public ICommand CreateBookingCommand { get; }

        public BookingListingViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            _bookings = new ObservableCollection<BookingViewModel>();

            var bookings = BookingService.GetBookings(b => true, b => new BookingViewModel()
            {
                CustomerReference = b.CustomerRef,
                Status = b.BookingStatus.Name,
                WindowStart = b.BookingWindowFrom,
                WindowEnd = b.BookingWindowTo,
                DriverName = b.Driver.Name,
                TrailerName = b.Trailer.Name,
                VehicleRegPlate = b.Vehicle.RegPlate,
                HaulierName = b.Haulier.Name

            });

            foreach( BookingViewModel b in bookings)
            {
                _bookings.Add(b);
            }

            CreateBookingCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, new CreateBookingViewModel(navigationStore, this));
            _navigationStore = navigationStore;
        }

        public void AddBooking(BookingViewModel booking) //Command would call this method
        {
            _bookings.Add(booking); //Doesn't update the ListBox on UI
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bookings)); // Not in Sean's tutorial. I added that code to try to trigger the notify but it doesn't work

            //UpdateBookings(); //Sean's code. It works but it doesn't do anything special other than clear collection and add items. 
        }

        private void UpdateBookings()
        {
            _bookings.Clear();

            foreach (BookingViewModel b in BookingService.GetBookings(b => true, b => new BookingViewModel()
            {
                CustomerReference = b.CustomerRef,
                WindowStart = b.BookingWindowFrom,
                WindowEnd = b.BookingWindowTo,
                DriverName = b.Driver.Name,
                VehicleRegPlate = b.Vehicle.RegPlate,
                TrailerName = b.Trailer.Name,
                HaulierName = b.Haulier.Name
            }))
            {
                _bookings.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm baffled as to why my ListBox is not updating... What can I do to make it update so I don't need to clear collection and update again?

Also why simple `_bookings.Add(booking);` doesn't update the ListBox but

```
_bookings.Clear();
_bookings.Add(b);
```

does?

**EDIT**

One thing maybe to point is that I'm calling `AddBooking` from another ViewModel while `BookingListingViewModel` is not at this point visible.
The `BookingListingViewModel` never goes out of scope as it's being passed to other ViewModel and it's just being set as `CurrentViewModel` after AddBooking finished.

**EDIT2** --> Deleted

**EDIT3**

Rest of the code

CreateBookingViewModel

```
        public ICommand SubmitCreateBookingCommand { get; }
        public ICommand CancelCreateBookingCommand { get; }

        public ICommand SelectDriverCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SelectVehicleCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SelectTrailerCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SelectHaulierCommand { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationStore"></param>
        /// <param name="returnViewModel">View model page should return to</param>
        public CreateBookingViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore, ViewModelBase returnViewModel) // returnViewModel is BookingListingViewModel here
        {
            WindowStart = DateTime.Now;
            WindowEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            SubmitCreateBookingCommand = new SubmitNewBookingCommand(navigationStore, this, returnViewModel);

            SelectDriverCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, new DriverListingViewModel(navigationStore, this));
            SelectVehicleCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, new VehicleListingViewModel(navigationStore, this));
            SelectTrailerCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, new TrailerListingViewModel(navigationStore, this));
            SelectHaulierCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, new HaulierListingViewModel(navigationStore, this));

            CancelCreateBookingCommand = new NavigateCommand(navigationStore, returnViewModel);


        }
```

SubmitNewBookingCommand

```
private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;
private readonly CreateBookingViewModel _createBookingViewModel;
private readonly ViewModelBase _returnViewModel;
private BookingRecord _validateBookingRecord;

public SubmitNewBookingCommand(NavigationStore navigationStore, CreateBookingViewModel createBookingViewModel, ViewModelBase returnViewModel)
{
    this._navigationStore = navigationStore;
    this._createBookingViewModel = createBookingViewModel;
    this._returnViewModel = returnViewModel;
    

    createBookingViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
}

public override void Execute(object parameter) 
{
    BookingRecord bookingRecord = new BookingRecord()
    {
        CustomerReference = _createBookingViewModel.CustomerReference,
        WindowStart = _createBookingViewModel.WindowStart,
        WindowEnd = _createBookingViewModel.WindowEnd,
        DriverId = _createBookingViewModel.DriverId,
        VehicleId = _createBookingViewModel.VehicleId,
        TrailerId = _createBookingViewModel.TrailerId,
        HaulierId = _createBookingViewModel.HaulierId,
        RequiresValidation = true
    };

    BookingService.CreateBooking(bookingRecord, out string[] feedback);

    BookingViewModel booking = BookingService.GetBooking(b => true, b => new BookingViewModel()
    {
        CustomerReference = b.CustomerRef,
        WindowStart = b.BookingWindowFrom,
        WindowEnd = b.BookingWindowTo,
        DriverName = b.Driver.Name,
        VehicleRegPlate = b.Vehicle.RegPlate,
        TrailerName = b.Trailer.Name,
        HaulierName = b.Haulier.Name
    });

    ((BookingListingViewModel)_returnViewModel).AddBooking(booking);
    _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = _returnViewModel;
}
```

The behaviour of my original question is still not answered...

Comment: Yes I am sure. When I restart the app the new line is visible on the list. Also when I use UpdateBookings method the ListBox updates

Comment: The problem is that you call AddBooking on *another* view model instance. That will obviously not work. Not sure if you really need an explanation for why it won't work. It should be clear that you are populating a collection to which the view is not bound.

Comment: My understanding was that class is passed as reference to the object. So if I make changes to passed class it would reflect it on calling class? This approach actually works on other places in my code but not here

Comment: I have one class that is passed around. It works with other ViewModel s but not here.

Comment: Ok. Let assume that's root cause of my issue. How do I solve it then?

Comment: But I am... I'm not creating new instance. I pass around the same instance of view model between other classes...

Comment: Then what does "*I'm calling AddBooking from another ViewModel*" mean exactly? Why would you not simply show us the relevant parts of that code?

Comment: I create `CreateBookingViewModel(navigationStore, this)` which in turn implements ICommand that calls AddBooking from passed argument. I'll add more code later when I access my pc

Comment: As you can also see I pass `navigationStore` around which holds CurrentViewModel. I reuse the same class to determine view that is to be displayed in screen

Comment: @Clemens see edit for code example where class passed to another class affects calling method.

Comment: What is NewClass and AnotherClass? Show us your actual code, i.e. SubmitBookingCommand or CreateBookingViewModel or whatever it *really* is.

Comment: @Clemens Edited with actual code

Comment: You have to debug your code to see if the `_bookings` field accessed in `AddBooking` is really the same as you had used before. Your conclusion "*//UpdateBookings(); //Sean's code. It works but it doesn't do anything special other than clear collection and add items.*" is perhaps incorrect. It may populate a possibly new collection with existing elements from the BookingService.

Comment: @Clemens It is the same. It works as I expected it. I use the same class through the code... I found my problem now when I looked into this again and it's in this line `BookingViewModel booking = BookingService.GetBooking(b =>true, b => new BookingViewModel()` which fetched first found item in the db which is not necessarily item I added as new... I'll post an answer now

Comment: Or just delete the question. The code is so convoluted that it is unlikely helpful for anybody else.

Comment: @Clemens convoluted? I don't suppose you can make it any simpler...

Comment: **1)** You ask why `UpdateBookings` is working but `AddBooking` doesn't - how about showing how you call `UpdateBookings`? **2)** What is `_navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = _returnViewModel;` all about? You obviously use some unknown navigation mechanism that changes the DataContext. **3)** You don't show the DataContext of the ListBox and how you set it. You only showed a useless snippet of your view. You should understand that reviewing one-line-code-snippets to find an error is pretty pretty pointless. Chances are that the error is in the context of the snippet.

Comment: => Everything looks like you are operating on different view model instances i.e. you don't update the binding source. The reason might be your navigation implementation. Please, if you need help, refactor your *complete* question i.e. rewrite it from scratch. Post coherent but minimal code. Show the complete context, which also includes how you navigate/switch DataContext and how you create and assign the DataContext of your ListView. If it runs in your IDE and reproduces the observed behavior, then we can review it. Currently there are too many missing pieces and too much unrelated code.

Comment: **[How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** - The bounty won't help if the question itself scares people away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem in my code was in `SubmitNewBookingCommand.Execute`
Following code retrieves first found item and not the one I added that's why I didn't see it... My db was populated with dozens of crap data so I didn't see it at first.

```
BookingViewModel booking = BookingService.GetBooking(b => true, b => new BookingViewModel()
            {
                CustomerReference = b.CustomerRef,
                WindowStart = b.BookingWindowFrom,
                WindowEnd = b.BookingWindowTo,
                DriverName = b.Driver.Name,
                VehicleRegPlate = b.Vehicle.RegPlate,
                TrailerName = b.Trailer.Name,
                HaulierName = b.Haulier.Name
            });
```

New Code

```
Booking newBooking = BookingService.CreateBooking(bookingRecord, out string[] feedback);

            BookingViewModel booking = BookingService.GetBooking(b => b.BookingId == newBooking.BookingId, b => new BookingViewModel()
            {
                CustomerReference = b.CustomerRef,
                WindowStart = b.BookingWindowFrom,
                WindowEnd = b.BookingWindowTo,
                DriverName = b.Driver.Name,
                VehicleRegPlate = b.Vehicle.RegPlate,
                TrailerName = b.Trailer.Name,
                HaulierName = b.Haulier.Name,
                Status = b.BookingStatus.Name
            });
```